# Read and write to a memory location

Tags: c

After doing lot of research in Google, I found this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int val;
    char *a = (char*) 0x1000;
    *a = 20;
    val = *a;
    printf("%d", val);
}
```

But it is throwing a run time error, at `*a = 20`.

So how can I write and read a specific memory location?

Comment: Are you sure you can write to `0x1000`? What platform is this?

Comment: @Banthar: Code blocks in windows

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is throwing a [segment violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) (SEGFAULT), as it should, as you don't know what is put in that address. Most likely, that is kernel space, and the hosting environment doesn't want you willy-nilly writing to another application's memory. You should only ever write to memory that you KNOW your program has access to, or you will have inexplicable crashes at runtime.

Comment: User code can't access kernel space (ring), that is the basics of modern operating systems, virtual memory and MMU. Otherwise you are correct.

Answer (score 19):

You are doing it except on your system you cannot write to this memory causing a segmentation fault.

A segmentation fault (often shortened to segfault), bus error or access violation is generally **an attempt to access memory that the CPU cannot physically address**. It occurs when the hardware notifies an operating system about a memory access violation. The OS kernel then sends a signal to the process which caused the exception. By default, the process receiving the signal dumps core and terminates. The default signal handler can also be overridden to customize how the signal is handled.

If you are interested in knowing more look up MMU on wikipedia.

Here is how to legally request memory from the heap. The `malloc()` function takes a number of bytes to allocate as a parameter. Please note that every `malloc()` should be matched by a `free()` call to that same memory after you are done using it. The `free()` call should normally be in the same function as where you called `malloc()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int val;
    char *a;

    a = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);

    *a = 20;
    val = (int)*a;
    printf("%d", val);

    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

You can also allocate memory on the stack in a very simple way like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int val;
    char *a;
    char b;

    a = &b;
    *a = 20;
    val = (int)*a;

    printf("%d", val);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might I ask why you don't just stack-allocate a char, and get the address of it? Seems overly complex for a simple example.

Comment: A heap allocation example almost necessary. The goal here is clearly to understand proper memory allocation not to repair a broken program.

Answer (score 5):

If you are running your code in user space(which you are), then all the addresses you get are ***virtual addresses*** and not ***physical addresses***. You cannot just assume and write to any virtual address.
In fact with virtual memory model you cannot just assume any address to be a valid address.It is up to the memory manager to return valid addresses to the compiler implementation which the handles it to your user program and not the other way round.

In order that your program be able to write to an address:

1. It should be a valid virtual address
2. It should accessible to the address space of your program

Answer (score 3):

You can't just write at any random address. You can only modify the contents of memory where your program can write.

If you need to modify contents of some variable, thats why pointers are for.

```
char a = 'x';
char* ptr = &a; // stored at some 0x....
*ptr = 'b'; // you just wrote at 0x....
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue of permission, the OS will protect memory space from random access.

You didn't specify the exact error, but my guess is you are getting a "`segmentation fault`" which would clearly indicate a memory access violation.

Answer (score 1):

You can write to a specific memory location.

But only when you have the rights to write to that location.

What you are getting, is the operating system forbidding you to write to `0x1000`.

Comment: I am running it in code::blocks. It gives segmentation fault `SIGEGEV` error while debugging

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak That information doesn't really alter my answer :-)

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak No it is giving you SIGSEGV (note the spelling), which is the POSIX term for when a program is accessing invalid memory location, aka segementation fault.

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct way to write data to memory location 0x1000. But in this day and age of virtual memory, you almost never know the actual memory location you want to write to in advance, so this type of thing is never used.

If you can tell us the *actual* problem you're trying to solve with this, maybe we can help.

Comment: I meant _why_ are you trying to write to a particular memory address? What is it that the program you are writing is supposed to do?

Comment: I attended an interview there they asked me the same. That is why

Answer (score 1):

You cannot randomly pick a memory location and write to. The memory location must be allocated to you and must be writable.

Generally speaking, you can get the reference/address of a variable with `&` and write data on it. Or you can use malloc() to ask for space on heap to write data to.

This answer only covers how to write and read data on memory. But I don't cover how to do it in the correct way, so that the program functions normally. Other answer probably covers this better than mine.

Comment: I know `malloc` will help. But without using `malloc` how to do it?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: It depends on the application. But for the sake of just writing and reading (and even crashing the program), you can declare local variable, or global variable, then get the reference to it and write data to it.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak, you can't just decide not to use `malloc` just because you don't want to use it. If you need a variable to be accessible outside of the scope in which it is declared, you need `malloc`. For local scope, you can just allocate on the stack the way other answers have suggested. What you cannot do is just randomly choose some memory address and write there. You don't get to control that.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to be sure about memory location where you want to write into.
Then, check if you have enough permission to write or not.