# How can I change a tuple in Python? (if possible)

Tags: python, tuples

In python, tuples are *considered* immutable. However, I want to know if tuples can be modified by editing the computer's memory. In order to edit the computer's memory, I was thinking that I could invert the built in `id` function in order to write to that memory location the new tuple. I am curious about this because I want to know out of curiosity if tuples are really as immutable as they were designed to be.

Comment: “if tuples are really as immutable as they were designed to be.” — Yes, they are immutable *as they are designed to be*. Subverting the type system by hacking memory locations doesn’t change that because tuples are *not* designed for that use-case.

Comment: Take a look at [`PyTuple_SetItem`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_SetItem), but don't tell anyone I told you about it.

Comment: Interesting article on tuples being immutable except when they hold a reference to another object such as a list --http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/10/python-tuples-immutable-but-potentially-changing.html

Comment: If you're going to even attempt to manipulate the raw computer memory you'll be in for a world of pain

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706483/2886575) answers this question in the positive for integers (which are also immutable in python), and could be extended to tuples with a little effort.

Comment: @DarrylG no, they are still immutable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I can change the content of a list in a tuple (so the entire tuple is not constant).  Example.  t = (2, [3]); print(hex(id(t)))    #0x7fcf9c274690;
print(hex(id(t[1]))) # 0x7fcf9c531140;
t[1].append(4)
print(hex(id(t)))    # 0x7fcf9c274690 (same)
print(hex(id(t[1]))) # 0x7fcf9c531140 (changed).

Comment: @DarrylG I understand what you are saying, but yet, *the tuple hasn't changed*

Answer (score -1):

This might be interesting example for you

```
t = (1, [2])
print(t)
try:
  t[1] += [1]
except TypeError as error:
  print("Error occured", error)
finally:
  print(t)
```

Output:

```
(1, [2])
Error occured 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
(1, [2, 1])
```

Comment: Yep.  Tuples are only as immutable as the objects inside them.

Comment: This is just an obfuscated way of doing `t[1].append(1)`.  It's not really in the spirit of the question.

Comment: The *tuple isn't being mutated here*