# Filling data to a given pointer(cpp pointer) in python

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, pointers, pytest

I have a scenario, where I receive c++ pointer in pytest framework and I need to fill data to the memory location pointed by the pointer in python. How it can be done in python? Are there any packages which help me do this easily. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696575/writing-to-particular-address-in-memory-in-python does this answer your question?

Comment: Not really, I don't want to use CPython