# Accessing direct memory address and can we access directly any memory address?

Tags: pointers, memory

```
int main(void)
{
int *a=6;
printf("%d",*a);
return 0;
}
```

in this code  we are accessing direct some memory address let 6, we will get segmentation fault.Why??
And how can i access it without any error? Can i access memory address directly?
Memory management is feature of processor or OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read and write to a memory location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207783/read-and-write-to-a-memory-location)

Comment: somehow, but if i want to access that particular memory address how can i? and one more question it is dependent on OS or processor??

Answer (score 1):

each time you load a program it keeps to itself a range of addresses([Address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space)) that belong to it 
to over simplify it think of it like from address let's say 1000 till
4000 your stack and heap resides means you can allocate memory only in that rage, refer to these addresses and these addresses alone.
let's imagine a "what if" let's say we could actually access address 6 but in that location your OS actually have some super important data and by accident you write over that data. OS programmers were smart enough to not allow us accessing stuff we shouldn't.

Comment: i want to access that address 6 than how can i??